Blender render is less glossy than the viewport image
Basically, my render doesn't match the viewport image. Specifically, the most outer metal plate face that's facing the camera is significantly darker than the viewport image.
Things I checked:

viewport shading options Scene Lights and Scene World are enabled
all objects are visible, nothing is hidden
changing the object shader doesn't fix the problem

Any help and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.
Render Settings:

Rendered Image, most outer metal plate face that's facing the camera is significantly darker than the viewport image:

Object and World Shader, Viewport Shading, Visibility of all Objects:


Not sure it is "less glossy", you have black surfaces where there shouldn't be any.   What does your world shader looks like without the transparent option enabled in render properties > Film? Could you perhaps share your file so we can check directly by ourselves what's going on?
